# Wrapper class in C++

Tags: c++, wrapper

Say I have the following abstract class:

```
class AbstractClass {
  public:
    AbstractClass() {}
    virtual ~AbstractClass() {}
    virtual void virtMethod()
    {
       printf( "%p\n", this );
    }
    void method()
    {
      printf( "%p\n", this );
    }
    ...
};
```

And the following child classes:

```
class RawClass : public AbstractClass
{
  public:
    RawClass();
    ~RawClass();
    ...
};

class Wrapper : public AbstractClass
{
  public:
    Wrapper( AbstractClass* wrapee ) : _wrappee ( wrappee ) {}
    ~Wrapper() {};
    void virtMethod()
    {
      _wrappee->virtMethod();
    }
    ...

  private:
    AbstractClass _wrappee;
};
```

Now, say I do the following:

```
RawClass* r = new RawClass();
Wrapper* w = new Wrapper( r );
w->virtMethod(); // This prints the address of r
w->method(); // This prints the address of w
```

What I would like to happen is for calls to `w->method()` to behave the same as calls to `w->virtMethod()`. However, I can't do this without making `method()` virtual and writing an implementation of it in `Wrapper` which merely calls `RawClass::method()`.

I have clearly got some design issues here, but can't figure out a way to get this to work, whilst having `RawClass` and `Wrapper` prescribe to the same interface.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: That Wrapper class looks mighty weird. Its destructor is ~RawClass() ? It has a member named _rawClass that is an AbstractClass? I'm confused...

Comment: LiMuBei, ~RawClass() was a typo, and I've renamed _rawClass to hopefully make it clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should not derive Wrapper from **AbstractClass** and instead overload `->` operator like a [smart pointer](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/SmartPointers.aspx) so that methods of **AbstractClass** can be invoked

```
class Wrapper 
{
    AbstractClass* _rawClass;
  public:
    Wrapper( AbstractClass* wrapee ) : _rawClass( wrapee ) {}

    AbstractClass& operator* ()
    {
        return *_rawClass;
    }

    AbstractClass* operator-> ()
    {    
        return _rawClass;
    }

};
```

and call it like so

```
   RawClass* praw = new RawClass();
   Wrapper wrap(praw);
   wrap->virtMethod();
```

Boost or C++11 already does this for you if you use **shared_ptr**

Comment: for automatic operations `pointer->method = (*pointer).method` , `(*pointer).method = pointer[0].method` and `pointer->method = pointer[0].method` is truth. You forgot to override `AbstractClass& operator[] (int)`

Comment: I also missed the `== and !=` operators for brevity

Comment: I think if I'm going to get this to work, this is going to be the way forward. Thanks!